# What kind of software is this?

Tags: software

I was watching a Daniel Noroditsky stream and saw that he is using this application for analysis. I'm quite new to chess and I couldn't google it.

Does anybody know the name of this chess program?

[image: Unknown chess software]

Comment: As the already posted answer indicated, this is Chessbase, no doubt about it. Chessbase is the most well-known and popular chess database software on the market, and most professionals use it extensively.

Comment: I have chessbase 14 which looks exactly similar to this. But this could be a newer version I'm not sure

Comment: The takeaway for any software developers who read this: It's good to put the name of the currently open file in the title bar, but don't forget to also add the name of your software. You never know where screen shots end up, and you might be missing a great opportunity to promote your product.

Comment: Ivanchuk was using the same on his twitch stream. Go check him out if you're interested

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's ChessBase GUI with some bundled engine.

Here's a screenshot from [ChessBase's official documentation](http://help.chessbase.com/CBase/16/Eng/index.html?default_engine.htm), for reference:

[image]